# Paypal IPN Listener c# error.

Tags: c#, webforms, paypal-ipn

I am new to asp.net webforms.
Here is my code.

string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

```
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);
            //Set values for the request back
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
            string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
            strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-  validate";
            req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
            StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();
            if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
            {   
               TestSave();           
             }
            else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
            {               }
            else
            {               }
```

Comment: First of all please clear your all scenario and explain your problem that where you are getting error.  And also explained type of error like compiled one or run time.

Comment: on paypal website IPN notification history showing the status of msg "Retrying".

Comment: and this block of code is not running
 if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
            {   
               TestSave();           
             }